# How to close the newly created instance of webdriver in geb

Tags: spock, geb

I've been looking into some webdriver automation scripts using geb and spock. In few specs, I want another instance of webdriver with different capabilities so I'd not be using driver instance created by Geb by default. But when I use driver.close() in cleanup of test, GebReporting fails satating, NoSuchSessionException. I'm facing this issue after upgrading to firefox 74. Below is the script i've now.

```
Spec
  Test
     -- reset browser
     -- clearchacheAndShutdownDriver
     -- browser.driver = create new driver with new capabilities
    cleanup : driver.close
```

Now after cleanup the driver is closed and GebReporting uses the driver instance which fails with NoSuchSessionException. Is there anyway to handle it in Geb way? instead of doing only clearcache, store the instance in other variable, restore it to browser.driver after closing the newly created driver instance.

I did found a post with similar question but it didn't help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `resetBrowser()` on your spec instance before calling `driver.close()` to ensure that the `Browser` instance which is holding a reference to the `WebDriver` instance you are closing is detached from the spec and therefore no reporting is attempted at the end of the spec.